# selenium "find_element_by_id" can not find element on online bank?

Tags: python, selenium

I want to do some auto transactions on an online bank.
but can't find the login element?

I use the same logic on Google, which can find the input box element.
but can not find an online bank login input box element
somebody can help!!
thank you.

my script on below

```
driver.webdriver.Chrome("C:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://ebank.esunbank.com.tw")
driver.find_element_by_id('loginform:custid').send_keys('test123')
```

response↓↓

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"loginform:custid"}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KG9Bz.jpg)

Comment: I tried myself, explicit waits also dont work, because it is within an i-frame, try find out how to get something in an i-frame

Answer (score 0):

I try to use Selenium IDE
export python code, and compare how diff

now I know,
I lost this script

```
driver.switch_to.frame(0)
```

New question

I don't create a new page
why I need to use switch_to ??